# Cut time series into specific bins and label each chunk

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some experimental data on CO2 values over a few days in a room which are time and date-stamped. I would like to break it up into a series of "experiments" based on an experiment list of when each experiment happened.
[image]
e.g.

Data

```
df<-data.frame(CO2.ppm.=runif(10), Date.time.=as.POSIXct(" 2019-2-08 07:00:00") + runif(n=10, min=0, max=3600))
```

List of experiments with start and stop times:

```
ExpertimentList<- data.frame(StartTime=c("2019-2-08 07:10:00", "2019-2-08 07:15:00", "2019-2-08 08:30:00"), StopTime=c("2019-2-08 07:12:00","2019-2-08 07:16:00","2019-2-08 08:15:00"),ExptID=c(1,2,3))
```

Note there is time when CO2 is measured but no experiment is happening. E.g. between 07:12:00 and 07:15:00.

I would like to split `df$Date.time.` by `ExperimentList`'s `StartTime` and `StopTime`

So far I've converted everything to integers

```
df$Date.time.<-as.integer(df$Date.time.)
ExperimentList$StartTime<-as.integer(ExperimentList$StartTime
ExperimentList$StopTime<-as.integer(ExperimentList$StopTime)
```

Then looking at `cut`

```
breakz<-dplyr::arrange(paste(Experiment_List$StartTime,Experiment_List$StopTime)%>%as_tibble())

cut(df$Dev.Date.Time,breaks=unique(breakz$value))
```

But I can't filter out the data when no experiment was taking place. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

## **Expected output:**

```
set.seed(143)
data.frame(CO2.ppm.=runif(10), Date.time.=sort(as.POSIXct(" 2019-2-08 07:00:00") + runif(n=10, min=0, max=3600)),ExptID=c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

## ANSWER:

I found that I would run out of memory with @Ronak's answer so I chunked the data.frame into 10000 row segments:

```
df<-split(df, (as.numeric(rownames(df))-1) %/% 10000)
```

Then based on @Ronak's answer, I popped the code into a function and used mclapply from the parallel package.

#Do a left join to remove any rows not belonging to an experiment

```
fuzzyJoinFunction<-function(a){
  a<-fuzzy_left_join(a, Experiment_List, 
                       by = c('Dev.Date.Time' = 'StartTime', 'Dev.Date.Time'= 'StopTime'), 
                       match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`))
  a
}

df<-rbindlist(mclapply(X=df,FUN=fuzzyJoinFunction,mc.cores=4))
```

Comment: Can you include the expected output for the data shared?

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for looking into this. I have added an expected output to help. Also added a set.seed and sorted the time because otherwise it will vary. But with the values it has generated I have only found 1 CO2 value that is during an experiment in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join` to keep only the rows which are in range.

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

#All the datetime values should be of type POSIXct.
ExpertimentList %>%
  mutate(across(c(StartTime, StopTime), lubridate::ymd_hms)) -> ExpertimentList


fuzzy_inner_join(df, ExpertimentList, 
                 by = c('Date.time.' = 'StartTime', 'Date.time.'= 'StopTime'), 
                 match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`))
```

To get all `df` values in the final output with `NA` for `ExptID` use `fuzzy_left_join`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! even before I finished writing a comment above!

Comment: I'm finding my R session runs for about 30 minutes but then crashes. I tried it on a small (1000 rows) chunk on the data.frame and it works nicely but then crashes on larger sets (5E6 rows). What do you think is the best way forward?

Comment: I'm going to try chunking it and then binding at the end.